# MVVM and UserControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, viewmodel

I'm in a little  bit of a pickel, here it is:

I have a MainWindow.xaml using a userControl. This latter needs a path to function properly and has it passed through a public string property.

The MainWindow is coupled with a viewmodel in which I do the work needed to create the path needed above.

Is there a clean way to set the userControl's path property from the MainWindow.xaml, such as for instance a binding to one of its viewmodel's properties?
Something like

```
<uc:MyUserControl x:Name="controlsName" 
    PathPropertyNeeded="{Binding ViewModelsProperty}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a dependency property:

http://wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just need to ensure that `PathPropertyNeeded` is a [dependency property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.aspx).